# Rewriting function to be asynchrononous

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do I rewrite the following as an async function? It keeps returning referralUrl on the view as undefined:

**controller**

```ts
  createReferralUrls() {
    this.referralUrl = this.referralService.generateReferralUrl(this.userData.referralId);
    this.campaignMessage = 'Sign up here: ' + this.referralUrl + '.';
    this.facebookShareUrl = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + this.referralUrl;
    this.whatsappShareUrl = 'https://wa.me/?text=' + this.campaignMessage;
    this.twitterShareUrl = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + this.campaignMessage;
    this.emailShareUrl = 'mailto:?subject=Welcome to our site!&body=' + this.campaignMessage;
  }
```

**html**

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="{{ referralUrl }}" readonly>
```

**referralService**

```ts
  generateReferralUrl(referralId) {
    if (location.host === 'localhost:4200') {
      return 'localhost:4200/invite/' + referralId;
    } else if (location.host === 'myapp.herokuapp.com') {
      return 'myapp.herokuapp.com/invite/' + referralId;
    } else if (location.host === 'myapp.com') {
      return 'myapp.com/invite/' + referralId;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How is generateReferralUrl in referralservice generating the url?

Comment: i have posted it now please check

Comment: can you make your function return a default value because what seems is your service function is having nothing specifically as asynchronous code which may need observing or promising

Comment: @arpitsharma how can i do that if what it returns is environment specific

Comment: are you sure any of these "if conditions" is true if you are certain then you can try by banana boxing your input value

Comment: how do i do that can you please show me an example

Comment: @arpitsharma implement answer below, I get error: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Comment: banana boxing is like <input ([value])="referralId">. Yes below answer will not work because generateReferralUrl has not returned as observable.

Comment: @arpitsharma It's updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement Observable call here,

```
    createReferralUrls() {
       this.referralService.generateReferralUrl(this.userData.referralId)
        .subscribe(
         (res)=>{        
            this.campaignMessage = 'Sign up here: ' + res + '.';
            this.facebookShareUrl = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + res;
            this.whatsappShareUrl = 'https://wa.me/?text=' + this.campaignMessage;
            this.twitterShareUrl = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + this.campaignMessage;
            this.emailShareUrl = 'mailto:?subject=Welcome to our site!&body=' + this.campaignMessage;        
        }
       );      
      }
```

Please also add your service, so we can edit your service returning type as well.

**Update2:**
Change your service as below,

```
  generateReferralUrl(referralId) {
    if (location.host === 'localhost:4200') {
      return Observable.create((observer) => { observer.next('localhost:4200/invite/' + referralId) });
    } else if (location.host === 'myapp.herokuapp.com') {
      return Observable.create((observer) => { observer.next('myapp.herokuapp.com/invite/' + referralId) });
    } else if (location.host === 'myapp.com') {
      return Observable.create((observer) => { observer.next('myapp.com/invite/' + referralId) });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I’ve included it

Comment: Please have a look when you have some time. I get the error: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Comment: Actually you service is not working like service, I've just noticed that.

Comment: Hi I get this error: `VM17:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:4200/invite/LHl9uvdY' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Comment: I’m not trying to retrieve data from an endpoint, just the text itself

Comment: My solution is not get request as well. It was because of assignment of Subscription, please remove this.referralSubscription

Answer (score 0):

Please change your input like this 
 `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" [value]="referralUrl" readonly>`